# Как отправить сообщение определённому пользователю через socket.io?

Tags: socket.io, php, сокет, javascript

Как отправлять сообщения только пользователям с определёнными ID?

Например, у меня есть пользователь с id=5 и я хочу отправить сообщение только ему, а не всем подключённым к сокету пользователям. Как можно передать этот id на сервер?

Client

```
<?php
$id=5; // id to send to
echo '
<div id="id">'.$id.'</div>
<div id="messages"></div>
<input type="text" id="type">
<div id="btn">Press</div>
';
?>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var id=$('#id').html();
var socket=io.connect('http://localhost:8010');
socket.on('connecting',function(){alert('Connecting');});
socket.on('connect',function(){alert('Connected');});
socket.on('message',function(data){message(data.text);});
function message(text){$('#messages').append(text+'<br>');}
$('#btn').click(function(){
    var text=$('#type').val();
    socket.emit("message",{text:text});
});
});
</script>
```

Server

```
io.sockets.on('connection',function(client){
    client.on('message',function(message){
        try{
            client.emit('message',message);
           client.broadcast.emit('message', message);
        }catch(e){
            console.log(e);
            client.disconnect();
        }
    });
});
```

Как передать id=5 на сервер?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  users.push(socket.id);
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('message', function(message) {
        // если такой пользователь существует
        if(users[message.user_id] != undefined) {
            // отправляем только ему сообщение
            io.sockets.connected[users[message.user_id]].emit('message', message);
        }
    });
});
```

Примерно так. Юзер подключается, заносим его в массив. Дальше просто отправляем номер ключа в массиве (т.е. кому хотим, чтобы дошло сообщение).

```
socket.emit("message", {
    'user_id' : document.getElementById('user_id').value,
    'message' : document.getElementById('message').value
});
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что document.getElementById('user_id').value не равен socket.id...

Нужно либо user_id передать на сервер и добавить в массив users, либо socket.id передать в client-file. Желательно первое.

Comment: ну так вам и говорят - привязать сокеты к юзерам  - сделать массив, потом user_id посылаете и получаете ссылку на socket_id, по которому и послаете мессагу.
 (@lampa а зачем этот крокодил почему бы socket в массив users не складывать ?, и потом ему emit и делать)