# Socket.io отправить сообщение определённому клиенту

Tags: node.js, socket.io, чат

Делаю чат обратной связи (`live chat`), используя

- socket.io
- nodejs
- php
- mysql

Работать он должен так. Пользователь хочет задать вопрос и отсылает сообщение. Менеджеру приходит уведомление (через подписку на события в `Redis`) в режиме реального времени о новом диалоге, переходит на страницу сообщений и начинает с пользователем диалог (для этого диалог сохраняю в базе данных). 
В базе данных (используя `node.js`) сохраняю socket.id, текст сообщения и т.д.
На данный момент имеются 2 больших проблемы.

1) Почему через некоторое время изменяется socket.id? Получается, 3-4 сообщения отправил в чате и socket.id изменился. Соответственно, в базе данных создался новый диалог.

2) Не получается отправить ответ-сообщение конкретному пользователю, с кем в данный момент ведётся диалог. Сообщение получают все клиенты, у кого в данный момент открыт сайт. Планировал так, когда менеджер захочет ответить на сообщение, информация о socket.id берётся из базы данных и высылается ответ.

Пример кода:

```
socket.on('message', function (msg) {
    var data = JSON.parse(msg);
    io.sockets.connected[data.socket_id].emit('ResponseMessage', data.message);
}
```

Так же использовал множество других методов, например

```
socket.to(data.socket_id).emit('ResponseMessage', data.message);
io.sockets.sockets(socket.id).emit'ResponseMessage', data.message);
io.socket.to(socket.id).emit'ResponseMessage', data.message);
```

но во всех случаях ошибки. Или нет такого метода, или сообщение вообще не доходит или доходит всем клиентам.
Спасибо!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как отправить сообщение определённому пользователю через socket.io?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/330889/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%91%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8e-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-socket-io)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем решил проблему следующим образом.
Пользователю задаётся куки с уникальным номером, если он впервые на сайте.
Когда он отправляет сообщение на Ноду, идёт сверка куки в базе данных....
Далее.
Хотим отправить пользователю сообщение.

```
socket.emit(cookie_userId, data);
```

Получаем сообщение.

```
  var userId = $.cookie("chat_guest_id");
socket.on(userId, function (msg) {
    var data = JSON.parse(msg);
}
```

Comment: И к тому же теперь можно каждому пользователю в чате выводить историю сообщений пока есть куки, связанные с данным диалогом.